# Finding non-empty grid cell in 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a 2-dimensional integer array (say 1000 by 1000), let's call it matrix. Each cell in this matrix has a X- and Y-coordinate (each from 0 to 999 in this example). Initially all grid cells have a value of 0. During program runtime, some of the matrix cells are set to another value <> 0.

Now I need a fast function (algorithm) that takes some X and Y values and returns the value of the matrix at that coordinates. However, if the matrix at the specified X/Y location is 0, then the algorithm should determine a non-zero value within the matrix that is as close to the original X/Y location as possible.

I have thought about looping around the original X/Y position with increasing offset at each loop cycle, but I am not sure whether this is really the fastest algorithm...

Any ideas? I would prefer Java code, but any pseudo-code is also fine :)

Thanks in advance for your help!
Kind regards, Matthias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the array is relatively sparse and the number of tests is high relative to the number of inserts, the naive approach could take a long time.

The alternative is to build a spatial-partition tree such as a quadtree or k-d tree. Nearest-neighbor search is O(ln N) at the cost of O(ln N) insert times.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any assumptions on how the matrix looks like, you must use brute force method to look at all values near the [X, Y] position.

1. just set 3x3 square with the [X, Y] position in the centre and test all values on the square perimeter
2. if you don't find the non-zero value, just continue with square 5x5, 7x7, etc., until you find something. You must handle the border of the big matrix.

It is just a work with for cycles, indices and proper ifs :-) There is no faster algorithm, because you don't have any information, guideline.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many lines / cols you expect to contain non-0 values.
If you expect for the grid of 1000x1000 to have < 100 locations filled you should store the information of what row & column is non-0 while generating the values.

If thats not an option use somthing like this:

```
public void foo() {
    int[][]matrix = new int[1000][1000];
    int x = 0,y = 0;
    if(matrix[x][y] != 0) return;
    int min = 0, max=0;
    boolean cont = true;
    foreverloop:
    while(cont) {
        min--;max++;
        for(int ii = min; ii < max; ii++) {
            // secure that min and max dont exeed matrix here.
            cont = false;
            int[] higherEnd = Arrays.copyOf(matrix[ii], max);
            int[] trunk = Arrays.copyOf(higherEnd, higherEnd.length-min);
            Arrays.sort(trunk);
            if(trunk[trunk.length-1] != 0) {
                // HIT! we search this distance but no further.
                trunk = Arrays.copyOf(higherEnd, higherEnd.length-min);
                int source = trunk.length;
                for(int distance = 0; ;distance++) {
                    if(source-distance>0) {
                        if(trunk[source-distance] != 0) {
                            // SCORE!
                            scoreHit(x+ii,y+source-distance);
                            break foreverloop;
                        }
                    }
                    if(source+distance<trunk.length) {
                        if(trunk[source+distance] != 0) {
                            // SCORE!
                            scoreHit(x+ii,y+source-distance);
                            break foreverloop;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void scoreHit(int x, int y) {
    // there could be several in nearly the same distances
}
```

you could optimize that by filtering out areas that you already searched, but I think that would make a difference only at higher distances from x,y